# Drawing elements that aren't on canvas - expensive?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm making a JavaScript game engine - [demo](http://www.jason-thomas.xyz/static/projects/radius_death_engine/?spiral) - and I'm wondering which of these options would be the least expensive for drawing on canvas:

- Have a condition to check if an object's x and y coords are within the  height and width ranges.
- Draw the objects regardless, although many won't appear.

The first option would require comparing four or so many variables, for each object and each animation loop. I'm wondering if that would be less expensive than drawing all objects regardless.

The actual game will have a number of objects that have x and y coords, with canvas that centres around the human player on a larger game map.

I use requestAnimationFrame to do the draw loop. I'm also not using any frameworks.

Comment: Why not use a profiler to check? It's best if you can use something closer to your real world scenario.

Comment: Sorry, showing my ignorance here - what is a profiler?

Comment: A profiler lets you measure performance. Here's an introduction to the Chrome profiler: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/cpu-profiling

Comment: Well that's awesome. I'll try both and let you guys know what happens

Comment: my two cents, if you only need to draw based on certain condition, better to always check, extra if or 4 ifs are trivial expense compared to single canvas drawing...

Answer (score 0):

Offscreen drawings are ignored by the GPU and therefore take less time to render (ummm--not render!). However the CPU will still process the drawing commands so offscreen drawings are not "free".

But you have a second performance hit. You are drawing every circle in its own path:

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(p.x,p.y,p.r,0,PI2);
ctx.fillStyle=p.color;
ctx.fill();
```

It's more efficient to draw all commonly colored arcs in a single (multi-circle) path:

```
ctx.fillStyle='red';
ctx.beginPath();
for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
    var p=players[i];
    if(p.color=='red'){
        ctx.moveTo(p.x,p.y);
        ctx.arc(p.x,p.y,p.r,0,PI2);
    }
}
ctx.fill();
```

Here's a highly non-optimized set of perf tests showing:

- Drawing on-screen circles with individual `beginPath` paths.
- Drawing off-screen circles with individual `beginPath` paths.
- Drawing on-screen circles with 1 multiple-circle path per color.
- Drawing off-screen circles with 1 multiple-circle path per color.

On my modest development computer these are the perf results:

- Onscreen  / individual paths:   1050ms
- Offscreen / individual paths:    427ms
- Onscreen  / one path per color:  528ms
- Offscreen / one path per color:  220ms

*highly non-optimized perf tests:*

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var colors=['red','green','blue','gold'];
var playersOnscreen=[];
var playersOffscreen=[];
for(var c=0;c<colors.length;c++){
    var color=colors[c];
    for(var p=0;p<100;p++){
        playersOnscreen.push({x:50,y:50,r:10,color:color});
    }
}
for(var c=0;c<colors.length;c++){
    var color=colors[c];
    for(var p=0;p<100;p++){
        playersOffscreen.push({x:-50,y:50,r:10,color:color});
    }
}

var count=100;
var t1=performance.now();
for(var i=0;i<count;i++){ drawIndividualPaths(playersOnscreen); }
var t2=performance.now();
for(var i=0;i<count;i++){ drawIndividualPaths(playersOffscreen); }
var t3=performance.now();
for(var i=0;i<count;i++){ drawColorPaths(playersOnscreen); }
var t4=performance.now();
for(var i=0;i<count;i++){ drawColorPaths(playersOffscreen); }
var t5=performance.now();
alert('onscreen/individual='+parseInt(t2-t1)+', offscreen/individual='+parseInt(t3-t2)+', onscreen/by color='+parseInt(t4-t3)+', offscreen/by color='+parseInt(t5-t4));

function drawIndividualPaths(players){
    var len=players.length;
    var PI2=Math.PI*2;
    for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
        var p=players[i];
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(p.x,p.y,p.r,0,PI2);
        ctx.fillStyle=p.color;
        ctx.fill();       
    }
}

function drawColorPaths(players){
    var len=players.length;
    var PI2=Math.PI*2;
    var clen=colors.length;
    for(var c=0;c<clen;c++){
        var color=colors[c];
        ctx.fillStyle=color;
        ctx.beginPath();
        for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
            var p=players[i];
            if(p.color==color){
                ctx.moveTo(p.x,p.y);
                ctx.arc(p.x,p.y,p.r,0,PI2);
            }
        }
        ctx.fill();
    }
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<h2>Please wait for perf tests to complete</h2>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```